# Loading HTML into Flash and printing with PrintJob() in ActionScript 3?

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is it possible to load HTML content into Flash from a URL and print it with PrintJob() with Actionscript 3 without the Windows print dialog showing?

This would cure a big headache.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can print without a dialog showing up.

As for the HTML content, what application type are you developing? In AIR, HTML content can be easily loaded and displayed via the `HTMLLoader`. You also might want to check out http://code.google.com/p/htmlwrapper/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I'm trying to do is to call a page which will take a URL parameter which will be used to retrieve content to print, specifically tickets being sent to a ticket printer. We had an ActiveX control but it doesn't work in Win7. After calling a page with the ActiveX control it took the parameter and sent the contents to the printer.

Comment: You could render the HTML out and print the container it's in. I'm not sure if your problem is the printing part or the disabling of the print dialog?